# Design advice -- avoiding "invalid covariant return type" when returning subclass

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following situation:

I specify a pure virtual function:

`virtual PredictedMatch PredictMatch(const Match &match) const = 0;`

I also have:

`class ImpactPredictedMatch : public PredictedMatch`

Now, I wanted to do:

`ImpactPredictedMatch PredictMatch(const Match &match) const;`

In a class which implements the pure virtual function from earlier. I'd assumed that the compiler would simply cast the returned type as necessary, but I get:

`impact_predictor.h:18:24: error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual ImpactPredictedMatch ImpactPredictor::PredictMatch(const Match&) const’
   ImpactPredictedMatch PredictMatch(const Match &match) const;`

I accept that this just doesn't work in C++, but I would really like your advice on what would be best to do instead. Do I have to return a pointer? I'd really rather not because I'd like automatic memory management, but is it the only way?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can only do this if returning by reference

Comment: IIRC, covariant return types are limited to pointers and references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you return an instance of a more-derived class, the calling code can expect to store in a variable of the base type.  In doing so, the result may be *sliced*, losing data and possibly leaking memory (at best).  If you need covariant return types, your only option is a pointer or reference type.  In both cases, you'll need to ensure that the object lives at least as long as the pointer/reference.

Comment: OK, so I can't avoid doing the memory management myself... Thanks!

Comment: Not if you want dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: don't forget std::shared_ptr

Comment: @marom: `shared_ptr` doesn't work for covariant (return) type. I mean `std::shared_ptr<Derived> f() override` is invalid :-(

Comment: Thanks everyone. I eventually went for returning a raw pointer, which I then immediately wrap in a unique_ptr. That seems to work pretty well, so thanks for the hint to look at smart pointers, marom!

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406037/2300278), covariance of return type only works with pointers or references.

You can try, however, to emulate covariance of return type with value types by using [name hidding](http://thesyntacticsugar.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/behind-scenes-name-hiding-in-c.html):

```
class Base {
public:
    // Non-virtual, simply delegates to the protected virtual method.
    // May be hidden in derived class in order to covariate the return type.
    PredictedMatch predictMatch(const Match &match) const {
        return this->doPredictMatch(match);
    }

protected:
    virtual PredictedMatch doPredictMatch(const Match &match) const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    // Hides Base::predictMatch()
    ImpactPredictedMatch predictMatch(const Match &match) const;

private:
    // Delegates to the specialized non-virtual member above
    PredictedMatch doPredictMatch(const Match &match) const {
        return this->predictMatch(match);  // Slices the object
    }
};
```

Member hiding is usually not regarded as good practice or recommended design tool. It may or may not be better than to return by pointer or reference depending on the specific class design you want to achieve.

One situation I've used name hiding like the example above was to implement a polymorphic `clone()` method returning an `std::unique_ptr` (rather than returning a raw pointer and hoping the user remembers to read the method's documentation and manage the object's lifetime correctly).

Note also that this design using "value covariance" assumes that you can either safely convert or slice the returned object without change in meaning. If that's not the case, then I believe returning by value or reference is your only choice.